# How to force UITabBar compact design when in landscape on iPhone X?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbar, iphone-x

So, I'm having a problem with the UITabBar on iPhone X.
The problem is that the tab bar doesn't adjust the icons when it is in landscape mode, like the UITabBarController.

1 - I've set the [safe area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9) settings.
2 - I've put the tab bar [inside a UI view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214740/ios-11-iphone-x-simulator-uitabbar-icons-and-titles-being-rendered-on-top-coveri).

But this only fixes the tab bar misplacement on iPhone X.

My problem is better described in the image below:

[image: See the difference between the landscape mode on each iPhone]

When running on iPhone 8 (anyone but iPhone X) the tab bar works like expected. But when running (the same view, with no changes) on iPhone X, the adjustment simply doesn't happen when in landscape mode. Is there a code that I should explicitly "tell" to the tab bar adjust?

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Comment: @ErAcube no solution so far

Comment: Same here. Did you find any solution? The problem is also showed in the interface builder.

Comment: Unfortunately no @dcorbatta